# How to check the space complexity of this program?

Tags: c

I have written my version of strstr function in c. I am using a temporary array of size 26. Then is the space complexity O(1) or O(n)?
This is my code :

```
void strcheck(char t[], int n, char p[], int m)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int temp[26];

    for (i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        temp[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        k = t[i] - 'a';
        temp[k]++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        k = p[j] - 'a';
        if (temp[k] > 0)
            temp[k]--;
        else
            break;
    }
    if (j == m)
        printf("string occured\n");
    else
        printf("not occured\n");
}
```

The program is working correctly just wanna know about space complexity. Thanks

Comment: simple function, no recursion, no dynamic allocation: `O(1)`

Comment: Nothing in your code takes different amounts of space depending on `n` (or any other variable for that matter).

Comment: FYI, your function does not do exactly as strstr, e.g. if you called strcheck with "omer" as t and "rome" as p, I think it will still state that the string occurred. If that's your intention, then you're good.

Answer (score 2):

This is using O(1) (also Big-Theta(1), as the best-case and worst-case use are the same figure) space-complexity as the the amount of space needed to perform the operation does not increase with n.